# Using AVAudioSession on iOS, how can I read the microphone audio samples in real-time?

Tags: ios, audio, real-time, microphone, avaudiosession

Apple has deprecated all Audio Session C api in iOS 7, therefore the whole approach of the famous Apple [AurioTouch](https://github.com/ooper-shlab/aurioTouch2.0-Swift) example code for real-time sound processing is no longer useful.

So I'm wondering how I must keep analyzing the audio data in real-time. I watched the WWDC video for 2013, and there they say that AVAudioSession has the ability to do so, but apparently they only went over it in their labs!!

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks alot!